# Replace the matched string in the comma separated string pattern

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

I have a comma separated strings inside brackets and I need to replace the string in matches the pattern.
And we have unknown string at the start and at the end. In the below example I need to replace c++ string with c if the row has string ruby.
I tried below sed command but it didnt work.

````
```
("java","php","ruby",".net","scala","c++",...n),
(".net","ruby","php","java","c++",...n),
("java",".net","ruby","php","c++",...n),
("ruby","java",".net","php","c++",...n);
```

```
sed -e "s/(\(.*\),\("ruby"\),\(.*\),"c++",\(.*\))/(\1,\2,\3,"c",\4)/g"
```
````

Comment: I don't understand; does `sed '/ruby/ s/c++/c/g' file` give you your required output?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the expected output and clarify if you're trying to only do replacements in a specific field or anywhere on the line or something else. Also clarify if you specifically only want to replace `c++` or just whatever string happens to be in the 2nd-last field or something else. We can't tell what you want to do by reading code that doesn't do what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like your sed command is not escaping double quotes

```
sed -e "s/(\(.*\),\("ruby"\),\(.*\),"c++",\(.*\))/(\1,\2,\3,"c",\4)/g"
```

change it to single quotes.

```
sed -e 's/(\(.*\),\("ruby"\),\(.*\),"c++",\(.*\))/(\1,\2,\3,"c",\4)/g' file.txt
```

or more simply use the below one...

```
sed -e 's/\("ruby"\),\(.*\),"c++"/\1,\2,"c"/g' my_file.txt
```

which will output

```
("jsjs","java",".net","php","c++",...n);
("java","php","ruby",".net","scala","c",...n),
(".net","ruby","php","java","c",...n),
("java",".net","ruby","php","c",...n),
("ruby","java",".net","php","c",...n);
("rubys","java",".net","php","c++",...n);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
("java","php","ruby",".net","scala","c++",...n),
(".net","ruby","php","java","c++",...n),
("java",".net","ruby","php","c++",...n),
("ruby","java",".net","php","c++",...n);
```

'

```
{m,n,g}awk '/\42ruby\42/ ? NF = NF : NF' FS='"c[+][+]"' OFS='"c"'
```

'

```
("java","php","ruby",".net","scala","c",...n),
(".net","ruby","php","java","c",...n),
("java",".net","ruby","php","c",...n),
("ruby","java",".net","php","c",...n);
```